# Changing receiver namespace without breaking already placed widgets

Tags: android, namespaces, widget

When I change the namespace of my widget provider, the widget goes blank and doesn't work until I delete it and add it again.

How would one change the namespace and the receiver name for a widget without breaking already placed widgets.

Before rename:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.creativitality.labs.timezoneswidget.WidgetProvider" android:label="@string/widget" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info_large" />
</receiver>
```

After moving and renaming provider:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.creativitality.labs.timezoneswidget.widget.WidgetLarge" android:label="@string/widget_4x1" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_info_large" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: I understand that renaming the receiver is advised against in the API guide. However, I'd like to figure out the best possible alternative.

For example:
- Force delete (old) active widgets that are no longer visible, but still occupy the space.

Answer (score 0):

For activities, you can create an `<activity-alias>` element in your manifest that points to the new name of the `<activity>`.

There is no solution for receivers. `<receiver-alias>` does not exist. Your receiver must keep its original name forever or it will break.